# std::shared_ptr use_count() value

Tags: c++, c++11

Could someone please help me out why the output is 2 and not 3? Thank you.

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int);
    std::shared_ptr<int> const& y = x;
    std::shared_ptr<int> z = y;
    std::cout << x.use_count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: you have an uninitialized int there, which is potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> const& y = x; //doesn't increase use_count()
```

Is declaring `y` as just a reference to `x`.  It is just like another name for the same object.  There is no `std::shared_ptr` object being created to increment the reference count.

Answer (score 8):

You only have two shared pointers: `x` and `z`.

Note that `y` is a variable but not an object. Its type is a reference type, not an object type.

(In C++, not every object is a variable, and not every variable is an object.)

Maybe the following code illustrates the way in which `y` does *not* hold a share of the ownership:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> x(new int());

std::shared_ptr<int> const& y = x;
assert(y.use_count() != 0);

x.reset();

assert(y.use_count() == 0);
```